# Как изменить цвет символов в консоли С++ на Linux?

Tags: c++, linux

Как изменить цвет символов в консольном приложении С++ на Linux? Использую MonoDevelop.

Comment: Что-то не пойму, что именно здесь отвечает за цвет

    cout << "\033[1;31mbold red text\033[0m\n";

Comment: Слеш 033 - это спецсимвол, который сообщает, что дальше будет не текст, а настройка параметров. закрывающая квадратная скобка - о том, что это будут параметры текста, а дальше, цифрами задаются цвета. Есть таблицы с расшифровками.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался

Comment: man console_codes

Comment: @Pavel_L

>Спасибо, разобрался

Тогда нажмите "Ответить на свой вопрос" и напишите как именно вы в этом разобрались (чтоб потом другие посетители форума не задавали тот же вопрос )

Comment: В строке cout << "\033[1;33m***"; ***- нужный текст, цифра перед m отвечает за цвет выводимой строки (ну и дальше всех строк), чтобы форматирование следующих строк не изменилось нужно (даже не знаю  как сказать) закрыть форматировние "\033[1;33m***\033[0m\n" (последнее \n необязательно - перевод строки)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#graphics - здесь есть таблица цветов. Возможно (наверное) все сложнее, но для моей задачи этого достаточно

Comment: Это подразумевает ANSI/ANSIW терминал...

Answer (score 2):

Это делается с помощью управляющих последовательностей. Смотрите, например, [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/94647/)

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << "\033[1;31mbold red text\033[0m\n";
```

[How do I output coloured text to a Linux terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616906/how-do-i-output-coloured-text-to-a-linux-terminal)